# Issue in finding a key value from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code that makes and tests a dictionary, like so:

```
Z = {
    "ID": "1234",
    "NAME": "ABC",
    "CITY": "HYD",
    "DEPT": {
        "LOC": {
            "PATH1": "/home/local/path_1",
            "PATH2": "/home/local/path_2"
        }
    }
}

print(type(Z))
print(Z.keys())
```

I get a result like `dict_keys(['ID', 'NAME', 'CITY', 'DEPT'])`.

How can I test, in the code, whether a given key (for example, `"LOC"`) is in the dictionary? It should be found for this example, because the `"DEPT"` value is a nested dict that has such a key.

Comment: Can `LOC` exist in any primary key, or will it only ever be in `DEPT`?

Comment: it will ever be in DEPT

Comment: Try `Z["DEPT"].keys()`.

Comment: Would something simple like `if 'LOC' in Z['DEPT']: print(True)` work?